# Switch to vertex, edge, face mode in edit mode via python

Tags: python, mesh, edit-mode

Is it possible to switch to vertex mode (and edge, face mode) via python. I know I can toggle between object mode and edit mode in python with

```
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

But how can I explicitly say I want to go in vertex mode?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="FACE")
```

[Look up the operator in the api documentation.](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=bpy.ops.mesh.select#bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode)

Comment: CoDEmanX's solution is much better because the scene doesn't get reloaded. It will be faster and also easier to use of course.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer to not use operators, if they can be avoided. You may use:

```
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode
```

Assign a tuple of 3 booleans to set *Vertex, Edge, Face* selection.

To activate vertex selection mode, use:

```
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True, False, False)
```

For edge + face multi-selection mode, use:

```
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (False, True, True)
```

etc.

---

When working with the [BMesh Module (bmesh)](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bmesh.html), there's also

```
bm.select_mode
```

For edge selection, do:

```
bm.select_mode = {'EDGE'}
```

For vertex and face selection multi-mode, do:

```
bm.select_mode = {'VERT', 'EDGE', 'FACE'}
```